# How to fix "Operation FindFriends (222) not called because client is not connected or not ready yet, client state: PeerCreated." in Photon

Tags: unity, photon, playfab

So here I am trying to add a Player as a friend to myself. I am following a tutorial for the same

So I am using the PlayFab to update the friend List. When the update is successful onFriendListSuccess() function is executed as given below.

```
private void onFriendListSuccess(GetFriendsListResult result)

  {

    friends = result.Friends;

    onFriendListUpdated?.Invoke(result.Friends);

   }
```

In the above function as seen onFriendListUpdated event is invoked.In the listener basically this is the code:

```
private void HandleFriendsUpdated(List<PlayFabFriendInfo> friends)

  {

    if (friends.Count !=0)

    {

      string[] friendDisplayNames = friends.Select(f => f.TitleDisplayName).ToArray();

      PhotonNetwork.FindFriends(friendDisplayNames)//-------------PROBLEM------------------

    }

    else

     {

      List<PhotonFriendInfo> friendList = new List<PhotonFriendInfo>();

      onDisplayFriends?.Invoke(friendList);

     }
```

But I am getting the following error as given here:

```
Operation FindFriends (222) not called because client is not connected or not ready yet, client state: PeerCreated

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)

Photon.Realtime.LoadBalancingClient:DebugReturn (ExitGames.Client.Photon.DebugLevel,string) (at Assets/Photon/PhotonRealtime/Code/LoadBalancingClient.cs:2564)

Photon.Realtime.LoadBalancingClient:CheckIfOpCanBeSent (byte,Photon.Realtime.ServerConnection,string) (at Assets/Photon/PhotonRealtime/Code/LoadBalancingClient.cs:2493)

Photon.Realtime.LoadBalancingClient:OpFindFriends (string[],Photon.Realtime.FindFriendsOptions) (at Assets/Photon/PhotonRealtime/Code/LoadBalancingClient.cs:1446)

Photon.Pun.PhotonNetwork:FindFriends (string[]) (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonNetwork.cs:2189)

PhotonFriendController:HandleFriendsUpdated (System.Collections.Generic.List`1<PlayFab.ClientModels.FriendInfo>) (at Assets/Scripts/MultiPlayer/PhotonFriendController.cs:33)

PlayFabFriendController:onFriendListSuccess (PlayFab.ClientModels.GetFriendsListResult) (at Assets/Scripts/MultiPlayer/PlayFabFriendController.cs:62)

PlayFab.Internal.PlayFabHttp/<>c__DisplayClass23_0`1<PlayFab.ClientModels.GetFriendsListResult>:<_MakeApiCall>b__1 () (at Assets/PlayFabSDK/Shared/Internal/PlayFabHttp/PlayFabHTTP.cs:215)

PlayFab.Internal.PlayFabUnityHttp:OnResponse (string,PlayFab.Internal.CallRequestContainer) (at Assets/PlayFabSDK/Shared/Internal/PlayFabHttp/PlayFabUnityHttp.cs:205)

PlayFab.Internal.PlayFabUnityHttp/<Post>d__12:MoveNext () (at Assets/PlayFabSDK/Shared/Internal/PlayFabHttp/PlayFabUnityHttp.cs:157)

UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator,intptr)
```

So how do u fix this error?

Comment: Why do you need to call `PhotonNetwork.FindFriends` again when you already got the list of your friends? And when you state you used a tutorial, it might be as well helpful to list the tutorial

Comment: Yeah, it is required for some stuff needed by PhotonChat which will be implemented in some time later....So here is the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVooS9nkZoU&t=754s&ab_channel=KnoxGameStudios. Thanks for the reply